# How to Appropriately Call a Static Method

Tags: java, static, static-methods

For the following code (I have linked from a previous question), I am told to make two variables (`dest_x` and `dest_y`) into `static` variables. I also made the `setDest` function `static` as well. This was easy. However, he states that I need to make sure this function is appropriately called from my `Model` class. What exactly is the appropriate way to do this? I understand that static functions don't require an object to be called, but in this situation, how will that work?

Thanks again, and here's the link to the code.

[GUI Making Arrays of Images that Move Using Mouse Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049313/gui-making-arrays-of-images-that-move-using-mouse-event/26051134?noredirect=1#comment40834765_26051134)

Comment: Can you produce a more compact piece of code for us to look at?

Comment: Have you looked at examples? There are tons of documentations and code bases you can check out.

Comment: Best if you post your current state of the code here along with the exact question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Model` class has

```
public void setDestination(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    for(int i = 0; i <3; i++)
    { 
        t[i].setDest(x, y);
    }    
}
```

which sets the destination for each turtle separately. If `setDest` is declared `static`, your compiler should warn you that

> The static method setDest(int, int, int, int) from the type Turtle should be **accessed in a static way**

(emphasis mine).

Accessing a method in a static way means that you should not (although you can as you see above) invoke the method call from an object, but rather from the class:

```
public void setDestination(int x, int y, int width, int height) {

    Turtle.setDest(x, y);   
}
```

As a side note, the arguments `int width` and `int height` are not used, so why does the method ask for them?

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. I did actually get that warning from my compiler. I meant to mention that. 

I'm not entirely sure why my method asks for them, as my teacher actually wrote this code. However, I am thinking it might be useful later on for some reason or another. I'm only part of the way through the assignment at this point. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If `setDest` is a `static` method of `Turtle`, you would call it by using the class name rather than via a specific instance, for example:

```
Turtle.setDest(x, y);
```